How common was holiday travel in Austria-Hungary?
How common was it to travel across different regions in Austria-Hungary for holiday trips? (e.g. people from Budapest to the beaches of Croatia)
If yes: How wealthy would have they been and what kind of accomodations did they use?

Railroads really changed the game, but were slow to develop during the 19th century. Fiume (Rijeka) and Abazzia (Opatija) for example could be reached by train from Budapest since 1873. Is that the period you are interested in, or are you looking for earlier modes of transportation?

Can you be more specific about the year you're interested in? Towards the end of the 19th century the rail network was very extensive but it would not have been so even 50 years earlier https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_Royal_Privileged_Austrian_State_Railway_Company#/media/File%3ARailway_Map_of_the_Austro-Hungarian_Monarchy_in_1874.png

I am reading a trip report from the very early 19th century, of someone traveling to Ragusa (now: Dubrovnik) and through Dalmatia. From what I gather (1) seaside vacations in Crotia were not a thing at that time (2) few roads, in poor condition (traveler used hired coaches); most traffic is by ship/boat along the coast (3) a severe dearth of hotels or even country inns, so traveler frequently struggles to find accommodation.

The first road was Karolina finished in 1728, connecting Karlovac and Bakar. Old and steep road was basically replaced by Louisiana between Karlovac and Rijeka finished in 1811.
First road to Dalmatia was built in 1787 from Žuta Lokva by Gospić and Knin to Zadar.
Railroad to Dalmatia was only built after WWI.

Seaside vacations were not a thing in the early 19th century, but spa towns were – always on the edge between healing your ailings with water treatments and spending leisure time in a relaxed environment. Especially Bohemia had those, the most famous one obviously Karlsbad (Karlovy Vary).
